# Расположение текста в одну линию

Tags: html, css

Вот картина

[image: снимок]

нужно сделать три текста, как на картине, вот html

```
<html>
<link rel = 'stylesheet' type='text/css' href= 'style.css'>
<p id= 'left_text'>Ut Enim Ad Minima</p>
<p id= 'middle_text'>Voluptatem Doleque</p>
<p id= 'right_text'> Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
</html>
```

Вот CSS

```
#left_text {
    color: #728461;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 152px;
}

#middle_text {
    color: #728461;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 40px;
}
#right_text {
    color: #728461;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 40px;
}
```

Не выходит. Вот даже когда в HTML пишу

```
<html>
<p id = 'a'>asdasdasdasd</p>
<p id = 'b'>asdasdasdasdad</p>
<p id = 'c'>asdasdasdasdadasd</p>
</html>
```

Тексты не в одной линии, и с div - так же. Как поступить? Спасибо.

Comment: @koko, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: 1. замени <p> на <div>  
2. используй float: left;  
3. используй margin-left вместо margin

Comment: +1, только первое не обязательно, т.к. оба являются блочными элементами. А вместо margin'а, лучше padding, меньше проблем с кроссбраузерностью.

Comment: просто как-то нелогично ставить сюда параграфы, поэтому я за дивы

Comment: Я тоже чаще использую дивы по привычке, даже там, где правильнее использовать параграфы, хотя, повторюсь, принципиальной разницы в них нет, кроме встроенного форматирования браузерами. ИМХО, могу ошибаться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, как вариант:

```
#left_text, #middle_text, #right_text{
  float:left;
  color: #728461;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

#middle_text {
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
.flex {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <p>Ut Enim Ad Minima</p>
  <p>Voluptatem Doleque</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего для этого использовать флекс и свойство **justify-content:space-between**.

Answer (score 0):

Для этого используется стилевое свойство **white-space** со значением **nowrap**, оно добавляется к нужному элементу с текстом.

```css
    .phone {
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
```